# JSONPath expression to find books having author name

Tags: json, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have the following json:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "República Brasileira. de Deodoro a Bolsonaro - 2° Edição",
            "writers": [
                {
                    "name": "Paulo Ghiraldelli Jr.",
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mariangela",
                    "id": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "writers": [
                {
                    "name": "Ilan Lapyda",
                    "id": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'm writing a JSONPath expression to find books that was written by "**Mariangela**". I have tried the following expression:

```
$.books[?(@.writers[*]['name']=='Mariangela')]
```

But I'm receiving "Invalid X-JSON-Path expression passed". What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My bad you are right, is this one so:

```
$.books[?(@.writers[?(@.name=='Mariangela')]).name]
```

Comment: Your expression will return the writer, but what I'm trying to accomplish is to return books written by a certain person.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Comment: It makes sense your expression but when I submit this to jsonpath.com tester, I got the error ```jsonPath: Unexpected token '?': _$_v.writers[?(_$_v.name=='Mariangela'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).